# Creating new dataframes with rows of groups

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to extract the rows of each dataframe of my group and create new dataframes from them such that a new dataframe only consists of the first rows of the group, another new dataframe the second rows, another for the third rows and so on.. For instance, my dataframe is:

```
raw_data = {'regiment': ['Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts'],
    'name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze', 'Jacon', 'Ryaner', 'Sone', 'Sloan', 'Piger', 'Riani', 'Ali'],
    'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 2, 3],
    'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['regiment', 'name', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
df

      regiment      name  preTestScore  postTestScore
0   Nighthawks    Miller             4             25
1   Nighthawks  Jacobson            24             94
2   Nighthawks       Ali            31             57
3   Nighthawks    Milner             2             62
4     Dragoons     Cooze             3             70
5     Dragoons     Jacon             4             25
6     Dragoons    Ryaner            24             94
7     Dragoons      Sone            31             57
8       Scouts     Sloan             2             62
9       Scouts     Piger             3             70
10      Scouts     Riani             2             62
11      Scouts       Ali             3             70
```

and I grouped it as:

```
gb = df.groupby("regiment")

   regiment   name  preTestScore  postTestScore
8    Scouts  Sloan             2             62
9    Scouts  Piger             3             70
10   Scouts  Riani             2             62
11   Scouts    Ali             3             70
------------------
     regiment      name  preTestScore  postTestScore
0  Nighthawks    Miller             4             25
1  Nighthawks  Jacobson            24             94
2  Nighthawks       Ali            31             57
3  Nighthawks    Milner             2             62
------------------
   regiment    name  preTestScore  postTestScore
4  Dragoons   Cooze             3             70
5  Dragoons   Jacon             4             25
6  Dragoons  Ryaner            24             94
7  Dragoons    Sone            31             57
------------------
```

I want to create dataframes such as:

dataframe with the first rows:

```
    regiment        name         preTestScore  postTestScore
8    Scouts        Sloan              2             62
0    Nighthawks    Miller             4             25
4    Dragoons      Cooze              3             70
```

dataframe with the second rows:

```
   regiment          name        preTestScore  postTestScore
9    Scouts         Piger             3             70
1    Nighthawks    Jacobson           24            94
5    Dragoons       Jacon             4             25
```

and so on.

I was thinking of using Group.apply() but I'm not too sure.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do this with a nested `groupby` with `cumcount`, e.g. this will group all the first occurrences of the regiments, all the second occurrences of the regiments, etc.:

```
In []:
[g for _, g in df.groupby(df.groupby('regiment').cumcount())]

Out[]:
[     regiment    name  preTestScore  postTestScore
 0  Nighthawks  Miller             4             25
 4    Dragoons   Cooze             3             70
 8      Scouts   Sloan             2             62,
      regiment      name  preTestScore  postTestScore
 1  Nighthawks  Jacobson            24             94
 5    Dragoons     Jacon             4             25
 9      Scouts     Piger             3             70,
       regiment    name  preTestScore  postTestScore
 2   Nighthawks     Ali            31             57
 6     Dragoons  Ryaner            24             94
 10      Scouts   Riani             2             62,
       regiment    name  preTestScore  postTestScore
 3   Nighthawks  Milner             2             62
 7     Dragoons    Sone            31             57
 11      Scouts     Ali             3             70]
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I don't think cumcount will be applicable on my group (my example is just a simple dataframe for illustration), but I'll note this for my future reference! Cheers!

Comment: I would be curious why you think this wouldn't work for your dataset. If I understood your requirements correctly this would meet them, it will group the first occurrences, second occurrences, ..., nth occurrences.

Comment: Apologies, I must have read the documentation wrong :( I've implemented this also with my code and the result is just as good. Thanks!

Comment: I've decided to mark this as the answer as there are no dependecies (can catch irregular number of rows without problems) and such. Today I learned lots of approaches. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are of course unordered.  Given that the sample data only has four rows per regiment, here is the ranking of the top four, which uses `nth` on the `groupby`.  The result was created using a dictionary comprehension iterating through range four (0, 1, 2, 3), taking the `nth` row of such value, and translating the value back to its ordinal name (e.g. 0 equals 'first').

```
d = {n: ordinal for n, ordinal in zip(
             range(5), ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'])}

top_n = 4
>>> {d[n]: df.groupby(['regiment']).nth(n) for n in range(top_n)}
{'first':               name  postTestScore  preTestScore
 regiment                                       
 Dragoons     Cooze             70             3
 Nighthawks  Miller             25             4
 Scouts       Sloan             62             2,
 'fourth':               name  postTestScore  preTestScore
 regiment                                       
 Dragoons      Sone             57            31
 Nighthawks  Milner             62             2
 Scouts         Ali             70             3,
 'second':                 name  postTestScore  preTestScore
 regiment                                         
 Dragoons       Jacon             25             4
 Nighthawks  Jacobson             94            24
 Scouts         Piger             70             3,
 'third':               name  postTestScore  preTestScore
 regiment                                       
 Dragoons    Ryaner             94            24
 Nighthawks     Ali             57            31
 Scouts       Riani             62             2}
```

For rows of different length:

```
df = df.iloc[1:-1, :]  # Drop first and last row.
>>> {d[n]: df.groupby(['regiment']).nth(n).reindex(sorted(df.regiment.unique())) 
     for n in range(top_n)}
{'first':                 name  postTestScore  preTestScore
 regiment                                         
 Dragoons       Cooze             70             3
 Nighthawks  Jacobson             94            24
 Scouts         Sloan             62             2,
 'fourth':             name  postTestScore  preTestScore
 regiment                                     
 Dragoons    Sone             57            31
 Nighthawks   NaN            NaN           NaN
 Scouts       NaN            NaN           NaN,
 'second':              name  postTestScore  preTestScore
 regiment                                      
 Dragoons    Jacon             25             4
 Nighthawks    Ali             57            31
 Scouts      Piger             70             3,
 'third':               name  postTestScore  preTestScore
 regiment                                       
 Dragoons    Ryaner             94            24
 Nighthawks  Milner             62             2
 Scouts       Riani             62             2}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Is there any way to create the dataframes by replacing 'first' with the row index?

Comment: I really like this implementation. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've decided to mark @AChampion's answer as there are no dependecies (can catch irregular number of rows without problems) and such. Today I learned lots of approaches. Thank you!

Comment: @c4mm11 You are free to choose which ever answer satisfies your requirements.  This solution, however, is easily modifiable to accommodate rows of different length.

Answer (score 1):

`groupby` on custom index, use `dicts` to store

```
In [67]: {x:g for x,g in df.sort_values(by='regiment',ascending=False).groupby(df.index%4)}
Out[67]:
{0:      regiment    name  preTestScore  postTestScore
 8      Scouts   Sloan             2             62
 0  Nighthawks  Miller             4             25
 4    Dragoons   Cooze             3             70,
 1:      regiment      name  preTestScore  postTestScore
 9      Scouts     Piger             3             70
 1  Nighthawks  Jacobson            24             94
 5    Dragoons     Jacon             4             25,
 2:       regiment    name  preTestScore  postTestScore
 10      Scouts   Riani             2             62
 2   Nighthawks     Ali            31             57
 6     Dragoons  Ryaner            24             94,
 3:       regiment    name  preTestScore  postTestScore
 11      Scouts     Ali             3             70
 3   Nighthawks  Milner             2             62
 7     Dragoons    Sone            31             57}
```

Or `list`

```
In [71]: grps = [g for _,g in (df.sort_values(by='regiment',ascending=False)
                                 .groupby(df.index%4))]

In [72]: grps[0]
Out[72]:
     regiment    name  preTestScore  postTestScore
8      Scouts   Sloan             2             62
0  Nighthawks  Miller             4             25
4    Dragoons   Cooze             3             70

In [73]: grps[1]
Out[73]:
     regiment      name  preTestScore  postTestScore
9      Scouts     Piger             3             70
1  Nighthawks  Jacobson            24             94
5    Dragoons     Jacon             4             25
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have a pre-existing group already (I have cleaned a file and grouped them with respect of NaNs and whitespaces). Should I combine them back and implement groupby on the custom index?

What is `df.index%4`, btw?

Comment: @c4mm11 Yes, this answer would imply you must.

Comment: I've decided to mark @AChampion's answer as there are no dependecies (can catch irregular number of rows without problems) and such. Today I learned lots of approaches. Thank you!